# Check if a value from a nested list is in anothere nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check if `list1[0]` value is contained in `list2[0]` and then `list1[1] -> list2[1]` ... so I get the same result as below:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]] 
list2 = [[2, 5], [4, 6, 8], [4]]


result = [[False, True, False], [False, False, True], [False, True, False]]
```

Comment: write a simple loop, do some movement, at least

Comment: Do you only want to compare the values of list1 with the first list of list 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested list comprehensions:

```
result = [[x in b for x in a] for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[False, True, False], [False, False, True], [False, True, False]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast respons :)